# Receive data via Bluetooth in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I have to realize an app that receive data via bluetooth from a **1D laser barcode scanner**, [here](http://www.inateck.de/inateck-bcst-10-laser-barcode-scanner-handscanner-handheld/) the description page.

This scanner works perfectly if you select, for example, an `EditText`: while the `EditText` has the focus, when you scan a barcode, it receives the content of the barcode and "magically" filled with this content.

The problem is that I would like not have the focus on an `EditText`, I would like the user scan the barcode, the app receive the data with a delegate method or in a socket, I parse the data and automatically put it in the correct EditText (every barcode have a check digit that permit me to recognize what is it).

The scanner is automatically connected via bluetooth so, I only need to understand how to stay listen on the socket and parsing the received data.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic involved :). That scanner is simulating a bluetooth keyboard (HID interface). Google removed the ability to connect L2CAP sockets starting in Android 4.2, so you probably won't be able to get a socket connection to the device. What you can do is capture the keyboard input the same as the EditText field does. You will need to get the input focus to your main window and override this function in your java code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
    {
    }
```

You will then be able to receive a series of characters from the device and build/parse the resulting strings.

Answer (score -3):

User zxing library for excellent barcode reading

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing

Voteup if it is helpful for you